# Use ODC file stored in SharePoint to connect InfoPath to SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, database-connection, infopath2010

I am trying to create an InfoPath 2010 form that does the following:

- Uses an ODC file which is stored in a SharePoint 2010 data connection library (for an SQL database)
- Connects to SQL Server 2008 (which resides on the same domain)
- Queries a table to pull results for use in the form

It works just fine when the ODC file is stored on my C drive, but as soon as the ODC file is uploaded to the connection library and I try to modify it (or create a new ODC file) the following error message appears:

`An unspecified error occurred while attempting to connect to the data source. Microsoft InfoPath supports only Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Access database. Check the connection to ensure it uses one of those two databases.`

If I manually modify the save location of a new ODC file to the SharePoint connection library the following window appears:

[image: Database Connection Window]

But it is promptly followed by the same error message:

[image: Connection Error Message]

I'm certain SharePoint and InfoPath can accommodate this... I am just not certain why it is occurring.

Comment: Ok looks like all I need to do is convert the connection to a file and host it on SharePoint... Double checking that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question. Just convert the connection to a file. In InfoPath 2010 this means **Data Tab>Data Connections>Select Desired Connection>Click "Convert To Connection File"**

You will then be prompted for a URL to save the file at. Easy as that...